# Pass the $index to a SlideNav

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-material

I'm creating a simple web page with three views (Home, List and Table) with users(name and city). In the table view I should be able to add data and edit the created data through a SlideNav (I'm using Angular Material). 
My problem is in the Editing Part. How can I pass the $index of the selected value to the forms inside the SlideNav? One time that I never change my page the regular solution of using the Routing isn't work.

Do you have any sugestion?

Comment: ng-click you have written one function ,in side that function pass data and $index as parameters

Comment: @Arun if I pass $index inside the function I receive an erros that $index is not defined

Comment: check this one http://jsfiddle.net/bdmRs/

Comment: @Arun your solution worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

You can set the data you want into the $rootScope. But, although it is easiest way, not it is not good to add data into rootScope, it will pollute the rootScope, and cause problem if you can not update those data properly.

The better way is to use a service, and pass the data in parameter in service calling. like:

```
angular.module('yourApp', [])
.factory('SomeService', function() {
  var theData;
  return {
    process: function(data) {
    // process the business logic here.
    this.theData = data; // hode the data here, and it can be used in other controller.
    },
    getData: function() {
    return this.theData;
    }
  };
});
```

Then you can get the data in other controller.

Comment: I tried your solution, the problem i'm figuring out is the fact that I never change the page so I can't even access to the value of $stateParams.index to store it in the $rootscope.